# Alien fleet falls diagonally

Tags: python

On page 266 of "Python Crash Course" when you're supposed to make the fleet fall one then change direction, my alien fleet falls diagonally. After using print statements I can see that the variable `fleetDirection` changes from 1 to -1 to 1 and so on. The problem is that it is constantly changing directions so it just falls. What should I do to fix this?

```
def check_edges(self):
    screenRect = self.screen.get_rect()

    if self.rect.right >= screenRect.right or self.rect.left <= 0:
        return True

def update(self):
    self.x += (self.settings.alienSpeed * self.settings.fleetDirection)
    self.rect.x = self.x
```

---

```
def check_fleet_edges(self):
    for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
        if alien.check_edges():
            self.change_fleet_direction()
            break
def change_fleet_direction(self):
    for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
        alien.rect.y += self.settings.fleetDropSpeed
    self.settings.fleetDirection *= -1
```

Comment: Your ```self.settings.fleetDirection *= -1``` just makes the fleetDirection switch from -1 to 1 for every change of direction.  What direction did you want it to go?

Comment: It switching form -1 to 1 makes the `self.x +=` line change the direction by a positive number instead of a negative number. Thus changing the direction.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: I've debugged my program and found the problem. The issue is I don't know how to fix the problem

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand what you mean by ```to make the fleet fall one then change direction, my alien fleet falls diagonally. ```  Can you please include some sort of debug information such as expected x,y values,  and actual x,y values?

Comment: When the fleet changes directions it is supposed to fall by 1 (Idk the measurement). But because `change_fleet_direction` is constantly being called it is constantly going down 1. Idk if I'm explaining this well enough or not but I hope it helps

Comment: You can find a working version of the code for this project, at this point in the game's development, [here](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e/tree/master/chapter_13/making_fleet_move). I copied your code into that working version. After changing your attribute names to match the book's naming conventions, the game still works correctly. I think your issue is somewhere else in your code. I think this kind of behavior usually comes from an indentation issue, but I don't see one here.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to add `UpdateAliends()` in the `run game` method.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the issue. In my `run_game` method I had `self.check_fleet_edges()` this made it so that when `check_edges` returned true then it constantly ran `check_fleet_edges()`. Thank you for giving me a link to the correct syntax; that helped me find the issue.